# Rotated UIImageView touchLocationInView not correct

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, location, tap

I have a `UIImageView` and when I touch it I can get the location of the touch with:

```
[touch locationInView:theUIImageView]
```

The problem is that when I rotate the UIImageView with:

```
theUIImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(arc4random()%15));
```

the `[touch locationInView:theUIImageView]` no longer returns the correct location of the tap! *gasp!

Any suggestions on how to get the `real tap location`?

Answer (score -1):

Choose a different (possibly parent, something not rotated) view to use in locationInView. If you need a different coordinate system from there, you can always add your own offsets based on the frame of theUIImageView before the rotation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure what your trying to explain

Comment: You call locationInView to get the location in a view. You happen to be using your rotated image view, but you can get the location of the touch inside the parent view by passing it to locationInView.